# How do I display the owner, groups and permissions for a user in bash?

Tags: permissions, users, group, accounts

Is there a specific command that will display the owner, group, and permissions for a user or will I need to run more than one command?

I just created the user "guest" in the /home/ directory and would like to display this information.  What command(s) can I use to find out this information? Are there even ownership for users or does that only apply to directories?

Comment: Owner group and permissions are associated with files, not users, so you probably want something like `ls -ld /home/guest`

Answer (score 3):

1. Owner: None, users do not have owners.
2. Groups:

   ```
   groups guest
   ```
3. Permissions (*Gnome* GUI, part of *gnome-system-tools* package on Ubuntu variants):

   ```
   users-admin
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Permissions are for files and directories.  There are separate permissions for the owner and a group.  Users can belong to groups.

To show the permissions for files and directories:

```
ls -l <filename | directory>
```

To show the groups a user belongs to

```
groups <username>
```